# How to say "consistency" (as in, consistently eating less, consistently working out, etc.)?

Tags: words

When I look up "consistent" on jisho.org, I get a bunch of words that I know aren't the "consistent" I'm looking for. A lot of the words are like "the facts aren't consistent".

The "consistent" I want is "performing something over and over again on the dot". E.g. "Consistently going for a jog in the morning has made my life better". In particular, the sentence I want to say is "If you want to lose weight, then what's most important is consistency." In Japanese, this would be something like "痩{や}せたいなら一番{いちばん}大事{だいじ}なのは_______だ。" What I want is the word that goes in the blank that means "consistency".

Comment: I'm Japanese. If I want to tell "Consistently going for a jog in the morning has made my life better" in Japanese, I use "継続" (keizoku).